# Perhaps this new formatting behaviour needs addressing

Tags: feature-request, formatting

[What is the name God gave Jesus? John 17:11](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/63734/what-is-the-name-god-gave-jesus-john-1711/68396#68396)

The link is an example of a rather garish new style of dropping oversized images into a post instead of the more *accepted* format for verse/quote display. There may be an issue using a mobile device or maybe it's just being lazy or/and wanting to stand out.

If not addressed now it will become worse and more common, due to device uptake/less PC based, or current precedence being accepted. A screenshot is provided below.

[image]

Comment: I agree that the oversized text is a problem. My downvote for that answer is not to do with oversizing as I hope that can be resolved, here, on Meta. My down vote was for other reasons, as I made clear in comment.